# pgloader mysql to Postgres command line exclude table

Tags: mysql, postgresql, pgloader

I have the following command that works.

pgloader --root-dir /tmp/ --with "batch rows = 500" --cast "type datetime to timestamp drop not null using zero-dates-to-null" --cast "type tinyint to smallint drop typemod" --cast "type timestamp to timestamp drop not null using zero-dates-to-null" --cast "type enum to varchar" --cast "type char to varchar" --cast "type date to date drop not null using zero-dates-to-null" mysql://XXXXX:YYYYY@127.0.0.1/test postgresql://XXXXX@127.0.0.1:5432/test

Is there an option to exclude a table?

Thanks